# Differentiate w.r.t. squared variable

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is it possible to differentiate symbolically w.r.t. some squared quantity in Mathematica? Evaluating something like

```
D[x^4 + 2 x^2 + 6, x^2]
```

gives the error message

```
General::ivar: x^2 is not a valid variable.
```

Is there some way around this without defining a new variable $y = x^2$?

Comment: What would be the derivative of $x^3$ wrt $x^2$?

Comment: @anderstood $\frac{3}{2} x$.

Comment: So, just `D[x^4 + 2 x^2 + 6, x] / D[x^2,x]`?

Comment: @swish I guess this should be an (if not the) answer.

Comment: By the chain rule, using implicit differentiation, Df/Dx^2 = (Df/Dx) / (Dx^2/Dx), so this method would also work in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From @swish's comment (but using [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html)):

```
myD[f_,x_]:=FullSimplify[Dt[f]/Dt[x]]

myD[x^3, x^2]
(* (3 x)/2 *)

myD[x^4 + 2 x^2 + 6, x^2]
(* 2 (1 + x^2) *)
```

If you need to specify constants, I would recommend the following:

```
myD[f_, x_, cons : OptionsPattern[Dt]] := 
 FullSimplify[Dt[f, cons]/Dt[x, cons] ]

myD[1/Sqrt[x^2 y^4 + m^4], y^3, Constants -> {x, m}]
(* -((2 x^2 y)/(3 (m^4 + x^2 y^4)^(3/2))) *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. Since I will apply `myD` to terms containing multiple independent variables for which `Dt` gives lots of extra terms containing differentials of variables that should really be treated as constant, I ended up going with the implementation `myD[f_,x_^n_]:=FullSimplify[D[f,x]/D[x^n,x]]`. For instance, for `f[y] = 1/Sqrt[x^2 y^4 + m^4]`, `myDt`, i.e. your implementation gives `myDt[f[y],y^3] = (-2 m^3 Dt[m] - x y^3 (y Dt[x] + 2 x Dt[y]))/(3 y^2 (m^4 + x^2 y^4)^(
 3/2) Dt[y])` whereas `myD` yields `myD[f[y],y^3] = -((2 x^2 y)/(3 (m^4 + x^2 y^4)^(3/2)))`.

Answer (score 10):

Temporarily replace `x^2` by `y` and then revert the change:

```
D[x^4 + 2 x^2 + 6 /. x -> Sqrt[y], y] /. y -> x^2
(* 2 + 2 x^2 *)
```

For the general case, furthermore use `Simplify` to replace `Sqrt[x^2]` in the final result by `x`:

```
Simplify[D[x^3 /. x -> Sqrt[y], y] /. y -> x^2, Assumptions -> x > 0]
(* (3 x)/2 *)
```