# Higher-order partial derivatives w.r.t. variable raised to some power

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is a follow-up question to [Differentiate w.r.t. squared variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135694/differentiate-w-r-t-squared-variable).

I want to be able to compute partial derivatives of the form $$\partial_{x^n}^m \, f(x) = \frac{\partial^m}{\partial^m x^n} \, f(x).$$
For instance, $\partial_{x^2}^2 \, x^4$ should give $2$, and
$$\partial_{x^3}^2 \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^3+y^2}} = \frac{7 x^6+20 x^3 y^2+40 y^4}{36 x \left(x^3+y^2\right)^{5/2}}.$$

What I have so far is

```
myD[f_, x_^n_] := FullSimplify[D[f, x]/D[x^n, x]]
```

This works great for computing first-order partial derivatives with respect to quantities raised to some power, i.e. derivatives of the form $\partial_{x^n} \, f(x)$.

To compute higher-order derivatives $\partial_{x^n}^m \, f(x)$ for $m > 1$, I would somehow need to store intermediate results after each differentiation and divide by the factor $\partial x^n/\partial x$ from the chain rule, before applying the next partial derivative. I'm fairly new to *Mathematica*, and I have no idea how to do this. Any help would be great.

Comment: Maybe read up on `Nest`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a formula adapted from [Todorov's paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102737515),

```
powerD[f_, x_^(k_.)] := powerD[f, {x^k, 1}];
powerD[f_, {x_^(k_.), 0}] := f;
powerD[f_, vars__] := Fold[powerD, f, {vars}];
powerD[f_, {x_^(k_.), n_Integer?Positive}] := 
       Det[Append[Table[(j!/i!) Binomial[k i, j] x^(k i - j), {i, n - 1}, {j, n}], 
                  Table[D[f, {x, j}], {j, n}]]]/(k x^(k - 1))^Binomial[n + 1, 2];
```

Some examples:

```
powerD[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], x^2] // Simplify
   (x^3 (7 x^3 + 10 y^2))/(4 (x^3 + y^2)^(3/2))

powerD[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], {x^3, 2}] // Simplify
   (7 x^6 + 20 x^3 y^2 + 40 y^4)/(36 x (x^3 + y^2)^(5/2))

powerD[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], {y^3, 3}] // Simplify
   -((x^5 (4 x^6 + 17 x^3 y^2 + 28 y^4))/(27 y^7 (x^3 + y^2)^(7/2)))

powerD[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], {x^2, 2}, {y, 3}] // Simplify
   (45 x (9 x^9 y - 88 x^6 y^3 + 84 x^3 y^5 - 8 y^7))/(16 (x^3 + y^2)^(11/2))
```

---

One can even use Todorov's results to define a more general function `parametricD[]`:

```
parametricD[f_, xv_] := parametricD[f, {xv, 1}];
parametricD[f_, {xv_, 0}] := f;
parametricD[f_, rest__] := Fold[parametricD, f, {rest}];

parametricD[f_, {xv_, n_Integer?Positive}] := Module[{fl, xl, xx},
          xl = Reduce`FreeVariables[xv];
          If[Length[xl] > 1, Return[$Failed]];
          fl = Reduce`FreeVariables[f];
          If[Intersection[xl, fl] === {}, Return[0]];
          xx = First[xl];
          Det[Append[Table[D[xv^i, {xx, j}]/i!, {i, n - 1}, {j, n}], 
                     Table[D[f, {xx, j}], {j, n}]]]/D[xv, xx]^Binomial[n + 1, 2]]
```

Some examples:

```
parametricD[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], {x^3, 2}] // Simplify
   (7 x^6 + 20 x^3 y^2 + 40 y^4)/(36 x (x^3 + y^2)^(5/2))

parametricD[(x^3 + y^2)/Sqrt[x^3 + y^3], x^2, {Log[y], 2}] // Simplify
   (3 x y^2 (x^3 (94 - 99 y) y^3 + 2 x^6 (-8 + 9 y) + y^6 (-25 + 18 y)))/
   (16 (x^3 + y^3)^(7/2))

parametricD[x y, BesselJ[2, x], BesselJ[3, y]] // Simplify
   4/((BesselJ[1, x] - BesselJ[3, x]) (BesselJ[2, y] - BesselJ[4, y]))
```

(Thanks to [Mike Spivey](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/78789) for pointing out Todorov's paper.)

Comment: Works like a charm, but I don't understand how. Could you explain what the last line in your definition of `powerD` does? For instance, why is `Append` needed? Also, am I understanding the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html) correctly in that the pattern `k_.` adopts the default value `k = 1` from the first line?

Comment: I linked to a paper in the very first line; you'll want to read it. The formula came from there. As for `k_.`: have a look at what `Power[x]` and `DefaultValues[Power]` returns.

Comment: Kinda wish I knew what was broken with the method given here so I can fix it; it seems someone was unsatisfied.

Answer (score 9):

Another method is to use `UpValues` as follows:

```
chainD[f_, z:{g_,_}|g_, x_] := Module[{v},
    v /: D[x, v, NonConstants->{x}] = 1/D[g,x];
    D[f, z /. g->v, NonConstants->{x}]
]
```

Then we find:

```
chainD[x^4, {x^2,2}, x]
Simplify @ chainD[x^5/Sqrt[x^3+y^2], {x^3, 2}, x] //TeXForm
```

> 2
>
> $\frac{7 x^6+20 x^3 y^2+40 y^4}{36 x
>    \left(x^3+y^2\right)^{5/2}}$

One can refine the method so that the variable x need not be specified, *(edit) and to handle multiple derivatives*:

```
chainD[f_, z_, r__] := Module[{res = Check[chainD[f, z], $Failed]},
    chainD[res, r] /; res=!=$Failed
]

chainD[f_, z_] := Module[{res = iD[f, z, Reduce`FreeVariables[z /. {g_, _} :> g]]},
    res /; res =!= $Failed
]

iD[f_, {g_, n_Integer?Positive}, {x_}] := Module[{v},
    v /: D[x, v, NonConstants->{x}] = 1/D[g, x];
    D[f, {v, n}, NonConstants->{x}]
]

iD[f_, g:Except[_List], {x_}] := Module[{v},
    v /: D[x, v, NonConstants->{x}] = 1/D[g,x];
    D[f, v, NonConstants->{x}]
]

iD[_, z:{g_, n_} | g_, x_] := (
    If[!MatchQ[x, {_}],
        Message[General::ivar, g],
        Message[chainD::dvar, n]
    ];
    $Failed
)

chainD::dvar = "Multiple derivative specifier `1` must be a non-negative integer";
```

And, here are some examples:

```
chainD[x^4,{x^2,2}]
Simplify@chainD[x^5/Sqrt[x^3+y^2],{x^3,2}]//TeXForm
```

> 2
>
> $\frac{7 x^6+20 x^3 y^2+40 y^4}{36 x
>    \left(x^3+y^2\right)^{5/2}}$

```
Simplify@chainD[(x^3+y^2)/Sqrt[x^3+y^3],x^2,{Log[y],2}]//TeXForm
```

> $\frac{3 x \left(2 x^6 (9 y-8) y^2+x^3 (94-99 y) y^5+(18
>    y-25) y^8\right)}{16 \left(x^3+y^3\right)^{7/2}}$

```
Simplify @ chainD[x y, BesselJ[2,x], BesselJ[3,y]]//TeXForm
```

> $\frac{4}{(J_1(x)-J_3(x)) (J_2(y)-J_4(y))}$

Note that contrary to some other suggested answers, `chainD` works with any function, not just powers or invertible functions.

Answer (score 5):

Basically the same answer I gave you before:

```
Simplify[D[
   x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2] /. x -> asdfljkhlh^(1/3), {asdfljkhlh, 2}] /. 
  asdfljkhlh -> x^3, Assumptions -> x > 0]
(* (7 x^6 + 20 x^3 y^2 + 40 y^4)/(36 x (x^3 + y^2)^(5/2)) *)
```

The advantage of this concept of replacing and back-replacing is that you can easily calculate higher order derivatives. The naming of the temporary variable is such that you won't run into name conflicts with existing variables (at least it would be highly unlikely that you name your other variables the same).

Answer (score 5):

Basically the same answer as [chuy gave before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135702/22013), with a proper use of `Nest`:

```
myD[f_, x_, cons : OptionsPattern[Dt]] := FullSimplify[Dt[f, cons]/Dt[x, cons]]
 (* chuy's function *)
```

Then

```
Nest[myD[#, x^2] &, x^4, 2]
```

> 2

```
Nest[myD[#, x^3, Constants -> y] &, x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], 2]
```

> $\frac{7 x^6+20 x^3 y^2+40 y^4}{36 x \left(x^3+y^2\right)^{5/2}}$

Wrapping in a function:

```
myDn[func_, var_, n_, cons : OptionsPattern[Dt]] := Nest[myD[#, var, cons] &, func, n]
```

so that

```
myDn[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], x^3, 2, Constants -> y]
```

is obviously also

> $\frac{7 x^6+20 x^3 y^2+40 y^4}{36 x \left(x^3+y^2\right)^{5/2}}$

and

```
myDn[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], y^3, 3, Constants -> x]
```

> $-\frac{x^5 \left(4 x^6+17 x^3 y^2+28 y^4\right)}{27 y^7
>    \left(x^3+y^2\right)^{7/2}}$

Comment: This works great!

Comment: You take derivatives w.r.t. both $x$ and $y$. Is it possible to modify `myDn` so as to be able to differentiate w.r.t. to multiple variables in one go, i.e. write something like `myDn[f,{x^m,n},{y^p,q}]`? That would bring `myDn` up to par with Mathematica's built-in derivative functions.

Comment: While `myDn[myDn[x^5/Sqrt[x^3 + y^2], x^2, 2, Constants -> y], y, 3, 
 Constants -> x]` works, making it a function is not that straightforward. J.M. has provided a general answer.