# How can I take derivatives recursively in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let's say I have the function

```
f[x_]:=x^50
```

I want to take one derivative and multiply the result by x recursively. That is, I want to

```
x D[x D[f[x],x],x]
```

but with an arbitrary amount of iterations. How can I implement this more elegantly?

Comment: Look at `Nest`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `Nest`.

```
Nest[x D[#, x] &, f[x], 2]
```

gives the expression you want. Change the last argument to control the number of recursions.

Answer (score 6):

Your process is equivalent to differentiating with respect to `Log[x]`. I gave a function, [chainD](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135778/45431) for performing these kinds of derivatives in my answer to [Higher-order partial derivatives w.r.t. variable raised to some power](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135769/45431). If you use this function:

```
chainD[x^50, Log[x]]
chainD[x^50, {Log[x], 20}]
```

> 50 x^50
>
> 9536743164062500000000000000000000 x^50

I should mention that you can manually apply the idea behind `chainD` with:

```
D[Exp[50 y], {y, 20}] /. y->Log[x]
```

> 9536743164062500000000000000000000 x^50

Answer (score 5):

```
dOp1[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 Nest[x*D[#, x] &, f[x], n]
```

For an undefined function `f`

```
Table[dOp1[f, n], {n, 0, 5}] // Expand // Column
```

[image]

Compare the coefficients with

```
Table[StirlingS2[n, m], {n, 0, 5}, {m, 0, n}] // Grid
```

[image]

Consequently, an alternative definition is

```
dOp2[f_, n_Integer?NonNegative] :=
 Sum[StirlingS2[n, m] D[f[x], {x, m}] x^m, {m, 0, n}]
```

Testing equivalence

```
And @@ Table[dOp1[f, n] == dOp2[f, n] // Simplify, {n, 0, 15}]

(*  True  *)
```

You can use a proof by induction to verify this.

For your specific `f`

```
f[x_] = x^50;

dOp2[f, 20]

(*  9536743164062500000000000000000000 x^50 *)
```