# How to define a function using nested derivatives?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

This is a follow up to my previous question [How can I take derivatives recursively in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139741/how-can-i-take-derivatives-recursively-in-mathematica?noredirect=1#comment377336_139741)
Consider

```
Nest[x D[#, x] &, x^5, 2]
```

This expression outputs

```
25 x^5
```

But when I try to define a function

```
test[x_]:=Nest[x D[#, x] &, x^5, 2]
```

And I evaluate say

```
test[2]
```

I am told that 2 is not a valid variable. How can I define this function?

Comment: What  is the expression `Nest[2 D[#, 2] &, 2^5, 2]` supposed to even do (when you throw 2 into `test`)? Can you expand on the end goal here?

Comment: You probably want something like `test[x0_] := Module[{x}, Nest[x  D[#, x] &, x^5, 2] /. x -> x0]`

Comment: @jjc385 that's an answer. I will be happy to accept it and upvote it if you write it

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution you are looking for is very simple.  In this case, you want to evaluate the RHS before assignment, so you should use `=` in place of `:=`

```
test[x_] = Nest[x D[#, x] &, x^5, 2]
(* 25 x^5 *)

test[2]
(* 800 *)
```

Comment: This fails if `x` has already been defined.  Consider:  `x = 1; test[x_] = Nest[x D[#, x] &, x^5, 2]` which yields `1 is not a valid variable.`

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution:just use another symbol to evaluate the derivatives,then use the parameter to replace the symbol:

```
test[x_] := Nest[y D[#, y] &, y^5, 2] /. y :> x
```

Comment: If the symbol `y` already has a value, this will fail.  But you can localize `y` by wrapping the right hand side with `Module[{y}, ... ]`, which makes it safe.  See my comment above.