# Take the derivative of a function of time by another function of time

Tags: functions, calculus-and-analysis

What I am asking could seem simple but I couldn't find a solution nor here nor in google. 
I want to take the derivative of a function by another function.
Let say I have two functions of time `y[t]` and `x[t]` (and some other parameters). In my code they both have a certain dependence on `t`. I would like to derive `y` by `x` and have the result expressed in function of time as well. Something like `D[y[t], x[t]]`. I know that I could simply calculate `D[y[t], t] / D[x[t], t]`. 
But isn't there a more direct way? Just out of curiosity ...

Comment: See `chainD` in my answer to [Higher-order partial derivatives w.r.t. variable raised to some power](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135769/higher-order-partial-derivatives-w-r-t-variable-raised-to-some-power)

Comment: This `D[y[t], t] / D[x[t], t]` actually is a most direct way. You may easily write a custom function for that, if you like. Something like `der[y_[t_], x_[t_]] := D[y[t], t]/D[x[t], t]`. Then `der[Sin[t], Cos[t]]` yields `-Cot[t]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thank you. That function works OK. Even though I am not into Mathematica language enough to understand why. Maybe it would take some time. If you could give me some hints I would be grateful but it is not vital for me at the moment so don't worry.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch you are right. The function that I wrote proved to be the most simple way that gets the job done. But it is always good to have feedback. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

How about using Dt instead of D

```
In[1]:= Dt[a[t] x[t] + b[t], x[t]]

Out[1]= a[t] + Dt[t, x[t]] x[t] Derivative[1][a][t] + 
 Dt[t, x[t]] Derivative[1][b][t]
```

Comment: I am sorry this is not working in my case. Maybe it is valid only in case you leave the functions unspecified. In my case the have a well defines dependence on `t`. To be more specific one is `a[t]=someparameters Log[t]` and the other is `b[t]=someotherparameters Log[t]`. And I would like to calculate `d a[t] / d b[t]`.