# Can DSolve give results in parametric form?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear, parametric-functions

Can DSolve give results in parametric form?

For example the [cycloid equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) is:

```
DSolve[{(x'[t])^2 == r/x[t] - 1}, x[t], t]
```

And the solution is usually given in parametric form:

$$x=r \,(t- Sin[t]) \quad y=r\,(1- Cos[t])$$

but Mathematica (10) give a resolt in terms of `InverseFunction`

So I wonder can DSolve give result in parametric form?

Comment: Are you sure that's the cycloid equation?  I've never seen it in that form.

Comment: Also, your parametric solution should be $x = r(t - \sin t)$ or something similar;  right now your parametric solution is just a circle.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You are right I corrected and added a link to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid

Comment: I don't believe `DSolve[]` is capable of parametric solutions yet. Here's another simple example (the *equiangular spiral*): `DSolve[{y'[x] == (x + y[x])/(x - y[x]), y[1] == 0}, y, x]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more an extended comment as a solution.  For convenience, begin from the ODE in the form given in the Wikipedia reference cited in the question.

```
y'[x]^2 == 2 r/y[x] - 1
```

The OP wishes `DSolve` to provide the parametric answer,

```
{y[t] -> r - r Cos[t], x[t] -> r (t - Sin[t])}
```

However, this result is not unique.  For instance, replacing `t` by `a t`, where `a` is any real constant, also is a valid parametric solution.  And, there are infinitely more equivalent parametric solutions.  Obtaining the desired solution requires specifying an additional relationship.

Here is a simple illustration.  Rewrite the ODE in terms of a parameter `t`.

```
y'[t]^2 == x'[t]^2 (2 r/y[t] - 1)
```

This ODE cannot, of course, be solved without a second relationship among `x`, `y`, and `t`.  For instance, specify

```
x'[t] == y[t]
```

(Other second equations are possible but yield different parametric representations.)  Now solve the set of ODEs, impose the boundary conditions that `x` and `y` vanish at `t == 0`, and simplify

```
FullSimplify[First@DSolve[{y'[t]^2 == x'[t]^2 (2 r/y[t] - 1), x'[t] == y[t], 
    x[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t] /. C[1] -> 0]

(* {y[t] -> r - r Cos[t], x[t] -> r (t - Sin[t])} *)
```

as desired.  This example is meant to show that `DSolve` is capable with assistance of producing parametric solutions.  It is not, however, capable of producing any particular parametric solution that someone might desire without very particular assistance.

Comment: As noted, a lot of manual intervention (and clever choices) is still necessary, since there are multiple ways to parametrize a curve. The functions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135769) should be helpful in converting the original DE to a corresponding parametric form.