# How to write a general derivative function of parametric equation?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/68988/a-general-formula-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-a-parametrically-defined-function/78789#78789) I see a mathematical method for finding higher order derivatives of parametric equations:

$$\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x & = f(t) \\
y & =  g(t) 
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm d^3 y}{\mathrm dx^3}=\frac{f'(t) \left(g^{(3)}(t) f'(t)-3 f''(t) g''(t)\right)+g'(t) \left(3 f''(t)^2-f^{(3)}(t)f'(t)\right)}{f'(t)^5}$$

$$\frac{d^n y}{dx^n} = \frac{1}{(f')^{n(n+1)/2}} \begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{f}{1!} & \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{f^2}{2!} & \cdots & \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{f^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} & \dfrac{dg}{dt} \\
\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \dfrac{f}{1!} & \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \dfrac{f^2}{2!} & \cdots & \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \dfrac{f^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} & \dfrac{d^2g}{dt^2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} \dfrac{f}{1!} & \dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} \dfrac{f^2}{2!} & \cdots & \dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} \dfrac{f^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} & \dfrac{d^ng}{dt^n}
\end{vmatrix}$$

I want to write a general and concise derivative function of parametric equation according to this principle.

What should I do to achieve this function succinctly and efficiently?

```
pd[1] = g'[t]/f'[t];
pd[n_] := D[pd[n - 1], t]*(1/D[f[t], t])
pd[3] // FullSimplify
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a variation of my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135778/45431) to [Higher-order partial derivatives w.r.t. variable raised to some power](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135769/45431):

```
ParametricD[g_, {f_,n_}, t_] := Module[{v},
    v/:D[t, v, NonConstants->{t}] = 1/D[f, t];
    D[g, {v, n}, NonConstants->{t}]
]
ParametricD[g_, f_, t_] := ParametricD[g, {f, 1}, t]
```

Then:

```
ParametricD[g[t], {f[t], 3}, t] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{3 f''(t)^2 g'(t)}{f'(t)^5}-\frac{3 f''(t) g''(t)}{f'(t)^4}-\frac{f^{(3)}(t)
>    g'(t)}{f'(t)^4}+\frac{g^{(3)}(t)}{f'(t)^3}$

which is equal to your result for $\frac{d^3 y}{d x^3}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. And I want to know how to generate this matrix $\frac{1}{(f')^{n(n+1)/2}} \begin{vmatrix} \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{f}{1!} & \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{f^2}{2!} & \cdots & \dfrac{d}{dt} \dfrac{f^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} & \dfrac{dg}{dt} \\
\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \dfrac{f}{1!} & \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \dfrac{f^2}{2!} & \cdots & \dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} \dfrac{f^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} & \dfrac{d^2g}{dt^2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} \dfrac{f}{1!} & \dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} \dfrac{f^2}{2!} & \cdots & \dfrac{d^n}{dt^n} \dfrac{f^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} & \dfrac{d^ng}{dt^n}
\end{vmatrix}$ simply.