# 'not a variable' error when applying D function

Tags: vector-calculus, differentials

I am trying to apply differentiation, D, operator in Mathematica to a vector. Importantly, I want to carry out the operation with respect to another vector. Basically, I am computing a Jacobian matrix.

Here is what I do:

```
Q = {\[Rho], \[Rho]u, \[Rho]v, \[Rho]T + \[Theta]\[Rho]T}
Ax1 = D[fx4, {Q}] // Expand
Ay1 = D[fy4, {Q}] // Expand
```

Where `Q` is the vector with respect which I want to differentiate vectors `fx4` and `fy4`. However, instead of carrying out the operation `Ax1 = D[fx4, {Q}] // Expand` Mathematica returns the following error

`General::ivar: \[Theta]\[Rho]T+\[Rho]T is not a valid variable.`

Do you know how I could bypass tis issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Differentiate w.r.t. squared variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135694/27951) and [How to take the derivative w.r.t. an arbitrary function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27392/27951).

Comment: Some of the symbols in your code are undefined.  Please edit you question to provide the missing information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First a variable can not be a sum: `ρT + θρT`. Replace this with a new variable, call it e.g.: `T`. Second, you must specify the arguments of a function. With this changes:

```
Q = {ρ, ρu, ρv, T}
D[fx4[ρ, ρu, ρv, T], {Q}]
```

[image]